# how to transform indidual xml messages into common XML document with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the below xml messages created by Tibco

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SalesInData>
    <COMPANYID>AIN2003</COMPANYID>
    <ENDDATE>20120825</ENDDATE>
    <FILENAME>2-SG4_2244_20120815.xml</FILENAME>
    <SalesInRecord>
        <ROW_NUM>7</ROW_NUM>
        <BUY_QTY>5</BUY_QTY>
        <HP_PRODUCT_ID>Apj45685</HP_PRODUCT_ID>
        <LOCATION_ID/>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XY</LOCATION_NAME>
        <UNIT_BUY_PRICE>999999999</UNIT_BUY_PRICE>
    </SalesInRecord>
    <STARTDATE>20120819</STARTDATE>
    <SUBMITDATE>20120827</SUBMITDATE>
</SalesInData>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SalesInData>
    <COMPANYID>AIN2003</COMPANYID>
    <ENDDATE>20120825</ENDDATE>
    <FILENAME>2-SG4_2244_20120815.xml</FILENAME>
    <SalesInRecord>
        <ROW_NUM>1</ROW_NUM>
        <BUY_QTY>5</BUY_QTY>
        <HP_PRODUCT_ID>Apj45678</HP_PRODUCT_ID>
        <LOCATION_ID>2-PQL-3401</LOCATION_ID>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
        <UNIT_BUY_PRICE>999999999</UNIT_BUY_PRICE>
    </SalesInRecord>
    <STARTDATE>20120819</STARTDATE>
    <SUBMITDATE>20120827</SUBMITDATE>
</SalesInData>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SalesInData>
    <COMPANYID>AIN2003</COMPANYID>
    <ENDDATE>20120825</ENDDATE>
    <FILENAME>2-SG4_2244_20120815.xml</FILENAME>
    <SalesInRecord>
        <ROW_NUM>1</ROW_NUM>
        <BUY_QTY>5</BUY_QTY>
        <HP_PRODUCT_ID>Apj45678</HP_PRODUCT_ID>
        <LOCATION_ID>2-PQL-3401</LOCATION_ID>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
        <UNIT_BUY_PRICE>999999999</UNIT_BUY_PRICE>
    </SalesInRecord>
    <STARTDATE>20120819</STARTDATE>
    <SUBMITDATE>20120827</SUBMITDATE>
</SalesInData>
```

but expected output will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SalesInData>
    <COMPANYID>AIN2003</COMPANYID>
    <ENDDATE>20120825</ENDDATE>
    <FILENAME>2-SG4_2244_20120815.xml</FILENAME>
    <SalesInRecord>
        <ROW_NUM>7</ROW_NUM>
        <BUY_QTY>5</BUY_QTY>
        <HP_PRODUCT_ID>Apj45685</HP_PRODUCT_ID>
        <LOCATION_ID/>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XY</LOCATION_NAME>
        <UNIT_BUY_PRICE>999999999</UNIT_BUY_PRICE>
        <GOODS_RECIVED_DATE/>
    </SalesInRecord>
    <SalesInRecord>
        <ROW_NUM>1</ROW_NUM>
        <BUY_QTY>5</BUY_QTY>
        <HP_PRODUCT_ID>Apj45678</HP_PRODUCT_ID>
        <LOCATION_ID>2-PQL-3401</LOCATION_ID>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
        <UNIT_BUY_PRICE>999999999</UNIT_BUY_PRICE>
        <GOODS_RECIVED_DATE/>
    </SalesInRecord>
    <SalesInRecord>
        <ROW_NUM>1</ROW_NUM>
        <BUY_QTY>5</BUY_QTY>
        <HP_PRODUCT_ID>Apj45678</HP_PRODUCT_ID>
        <LOCATION_ID>2-PQL-3401</LOCATION_ID>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
        <UNIT_BUY_PRICE>999999999</UNIT_BUY_PRICE>
        <GOODS_RECIVED_DATE/>
    </SalesInRecord>
    <STARTDATE>20120819</STARTDATE>
    <SUBMITDATE>20120827</SUBMITDATE>
</SalesInData>
```

but i want to transform this individual xml records which are created in tibco into single xml document with XSLT as shown above. please provide the code that can perform the task. there are some other elements which can be null.

Comment: Please read the FAQ here. This site is not the place for 'please provide the code' questions.

Comment: Tibco create a namespace for each xml record with a namespace but i want to group all the individual xml records into one xml document which can be parsed by a common XSD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input file is no well formed XML so no xslt processor will work with it. The only way I see is to produce a xml file at first and a simple xsl processing in the following step.

1. Remove the xml intros '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' for instance with sed or another tool
2. Put the result in your own root element
3. Do the desired xslt tranformation

`#simple bash example
sed -e 's/<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>//g' YOUR_INPUT > temp.file

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' > temp2.file

echo "<MyStart>" >> temp2.file

cat temp.file >> temp2.file

echo "</MyStart>" >> temp2.file

xsltproc YOUR_STYLESHEET temp2.file > YOUR_RESULT`